# Flipswitch - How to store a flipswitch state in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I would like to use the flipswitch code generated at:

https://www.cssportal.com/css3-flip-switch/

I'm an electrician by trade not a full time programmer. I would like to use this  ode to control a raspberry pi output. Simply I would like a variable to equal 1 when the flipswitch is ON and 0 when OFF.

Thanks

Comment: What code attempts have you made so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can save the state by getting the object and setting an `EventListener` on it. every time the switch is clicked it updates the `state` variable.

```
var state;

document.getElementById('fs').addEventListener('click', saveState);

function saveState() {
    state = document.getElementById('fs').checked;
}
```

You then have a boolean in state, that is either `true` or `false`